# Linking to category magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

I'm looking to get a product on a home page slider in magento to link to the category it is in... so far i have:

```
<?php
     $allIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
     foreach($allIds as $categoryId) {
          $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
?>
     <a href="<?php echo $category->getCategoryUrl() ?>"><?php echo$category->getName() ?></a><br/>
<?php
     }
?>
```

(this runs within a foreach item) This provides me with the categories (which is great), however the:

`<?php echo $category->getCategoryUrl() ?>`

Does not seem to link to the correct place (it actually doesn't give me anything). Can anyone help on the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show only one category link, you don't need to load categories in the loop:

```
$category = $product->getCategory();
$url = $category->getUrl();
```

Update: I just realized that the 1st line may not work on the homepage. But you still do not need the loop:

```
$category = $product->getCategoryCollection()->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: if i just echo out this $url = $category->getUrl(); the page breaks from there after.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category);?>
```

Comment: This seems to break it, nothing loads after this is called.

Answer (score 0):

You will find everything related to displaying categories and subcategories here [Display Categories and SubCategories in Magento](http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento.html). Hope this will be helpfull..